# CSS fonts on Android

Tags: android, css, font-face

I'm using `@font-face` to display League Gothic on a website, but it's not showing up on Android 1.6. Here's my code, generated with [Font Squirrel's @font-face generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LeagueGothicRegular';
    src: url('/fonts/League_Gothic-webfont.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('/fonts/League_Gothic-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('/fonts/League_Gothic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/fonts/League_Gothic-webfont.svg#webfont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

font-family:'LeagueGothicRegular',Impact,Charcoal,sans-serif;
```

It's not a big deal if `@font-face` isn't supported (I read that `@font-face` support is gone completely in Android 2). But League Gothic is quite condensed, so I would like to specify a better fallback font for Android than the default sans-serif so the design doesn't completely break.

Something like this would be perfect:
http://www.droidfonts.com/info/droid-sans-condensed-fonts/

But I can't find a definitive list of the default fonts that come with Android, and the name I should use to reference them in CSS.

**EDIT**
The answers so far missed the point (or I worded the question badly) - what I'm after is a list of system fonts that ship with Android. Something [like this](http://daringfireball.net/2007/07/iphone_fonts) for Android.

Comment: Looks like this may be fixed in android 2.2 - http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8655

Comment: Bryan: even with Android 2.2 the a bug regarding local() support (often used to work around and IE bug) still breaks Android. See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10609.

Comment: Hey Ben, were you able to use the Droid Fonts without embeding them with your app or on web? just from css, the way you mentioned in the accepted answer?

Comment: @HossainKhan didn't even try sorry, didn't get that accepted answer until a year later, I'd moved on :P

Comment: [Default font set on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809944/default-font-set-on-android)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The fonts that I see installed in my Android (2.2) system files are:

- Clockopia.ttf
- DroidSans-Bold.ttf
- DroidSans.ttf
- DroidSansArabic.ttf
- DroidSansFallback.ttf
- DroidSansHebrew.ttf
- DroidSansMono.ttf
- DroidSansThai.ttf
- DroidSerif-Bold.ttf
- DroidSerif-BoldItalic.ttf
- DroidSerif-Italic.ttf
- DroidSerif-Regular.ttf

Comment: For bonus points, any idea what names should be used to reference these fonts in CSS? e.g.
font-family:"Droid Sans",sans-serif;
or
font-family:DroidSans,sans-serif;
or something else?

Comment: Hey Ben, were you able to use the Droid Fonts without embeding them with your app or on web? just from css, the way you mentioned?

Answer (score 44):

I've had the exact same issue trying to get webfonts to work on **imeveryone**. As of now, there doesn't seem to be anywhere on the internet that states this directly, so I'll do it here:

***The 'local()' syntax used to [stop IE choking on file formats IE doesn't support](http://nicewebtype.com/notes/2009/10/30/how-to-use-css-font-face/) also [stops Android from loading fonts that Android does support](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10609).***

Oh dear. But it's easily fixed. The important thing is to ignore the 'Bulletproof Font Face' local IE workaround. It's a neat hack, and shouldn't break Android, but it does, blame Google.

[Android does support TTF and OTF](http://mwhenry.com/blog/2009/12/font-face-support-table/) files. The **proper syntax to support both Android and IE (and every other browser) happy is as follows**.

O 1) You need two separate style sheets for fonts, before any regular style sheets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/fonts.css" />
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styleiefonts.css}" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
<![endif]-->
```

O 2) In the normal style sheet, used by Android and most other browsers, don't use the local hack:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LeagueGothicRegular';
    src: url('/static/fonts/League_Gothic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('/static/fonts/League_Gothic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('/static/fonts/League_Gothic-webfont.svg#webfontOTINA1xY') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

O 3. In the IE specific style sheet, continue as normal:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LeagueGothicRegular';
    src: url('/static/fonts/League_Gothic-webfont.eot');
}
```

That's all you need to get working webfonts across all browsers. For now. **Someday Google will fix Android and MS will fix IE, so this answer won't apply anymore.**

Comment: FYI Trevor I've removed the curly braces, they were just leftovers from a Tornado template.

Answer (score 11):

I've heard, but haven't tested myself that the ["Mo' Bulletproofer"](http://readableweb.com/mo-bulletproofer-font-face-css-syntax/) method developed by Richard Fink works around all these issues (IE and Android) without the need for double stylesheets. The syntax is:

```
@font-face{ /* for IE */
font-family:'LeagueGothicRegular';
src:url(fishy.eot);
}
@font-face { /* for non-IE */
font-family: 'LeagueGothicRegular';
src:url(http://:/) format("No-IE-404"),url('/fonts/League_Gothic-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('/fonts/League_Gothic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/fonts/League_Gothic-webfont.svg#webfont') format('svg');
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have tested and can confirm this works across all major browsers, including Android 2.2 Thanks Ethan!

Comment: @nailer  what you think, can i embed another language font like armenian or  georgian font like this and show in browser text, which usually is shown by quadrat signs?