# Android WebView safe font family?

Tags: android, fonts, webview, font-family

No, like others, I don't want to use custom fonts. I am looking for **list of WebView safe fonts** that can be used without using CSS3's custom @font-face, which loads ttf/wof/eot font from web/local storage.

More refined question would be: 
**What are the list font's that are included with Android Operating System which can be used inside WebView?**

For example, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif, etc font can be used (not sure), so where exactly to look for to be 100% sure?

Thanks

Comment: I'm looking into Android 3.0 and above. Font should be globally available regardless of device OEM (Samsung/LG/Acer/Sony/etc).

Comment: [Is this helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200069/css-fonts-on-android/6012324#6012324)?

Comment: @Alex not exactly, these fonts can not be used inside WebView without using CSS3 @font-face (unless I am missing something). So, you can not just say: `body { font-family: "Droid Sans"; }` or `body { font-family: "Droid Serif"; }` .... none of them work. But `body { font-family: Arial; }` probably works, but I want to know where to look for list of available fonts like arial.

Comment: Okay here are some question which are very close to what I am looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532397/how-to-retrieve-a-list-of-available-installed-fonts-in-android - Says there is no way to retrive list of available fonts bundled for WebKit. And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809944/default-font-set-on-android - does not have the exact answer what I am also looking for.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

***Webview***: `It uses the WebKit rendering engine to display web pages`

According to the source code, `android.webkit.WebSettings` contains the following fields:

```
private String          mStandardFontFamily = "sans-serif";
private String          mFixedFontFamily = "monospace";
private String          mSansSerifFontFamily = "sans-serif";
private String          mSerifFontFamily = "serif";
private String          mCursiveFontFamily = "cursive";
private String          mFantasyFontFamily = "fantasy";
```

Accordingly, these are the fonts.

There is probably more fonts buried somewhere in the WebKit. However, they do not appear to be accessible.

---

This complies with the default fonts of Linux:

- **Sans-serif fonts**: Arial Black, Arial, Comic Sans MS, Trebuchet MS, and Verdana
- **Serif fonts**: Georgia and Times New Roman
- **Monospace fonts**: Andale Mono and Courier New
- **Fantasy fonts**: Impact and Webdings

---

Bottom line, there is no comprehensive list of fonts for the Android WebKit.

Comment: Understood! +1 for taking your time to clarify this. Thanks

Comment: Through my tests it seems that the Droid family is the only one included. Anything else should be free or will need to be licensed, and still included through CSS.

Comment: Are there in the meanwhile new fonts added on recent Android versions?

Comment: Can you help me how to solve my problem here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65108865/android-webview-custom-font-using-javascript