# Change font in webview code programmatically

Tags: android

I have a problem. I have to change the font in my webview. I mean I have a html page in assets and font of the html page is default font. I want to change font of the html page but it must be done in code in android application. This is possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796176/android-webview-font-size-change and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900658/how-to-change-font-face-of-webview-in-android

Comment: do u have custom fonts with u

Comment: @Raghunandan nice link.but he want in java code!

Comment: @Zala first link is in java code..

Comment: @Segi i see this but it's for size not for type. see the question require

Comment: I agree with Zala. I need do that in code of my application.

Comment: webSettings.getSansSerifFontFamily(); try this.

Comment: no effect. And I want to change font on Helvetica.

Comment: @edi233 check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setFixedFontFamily(java.lang.String) and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071174/android-webview-safe-font-family. i don't think its possible

Comment: @edi233 check this link for more clarity http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/webkit/WebSettings.java line 156 to 161. so helvetica is not supported. you can try the links in my first comment as an alternative