# What is the default font family taken by android webview to show its fonts?

Tags: android, android-webview, default-value, font-family

I am displaying my content on `Webview` as loadData method

```
  webview.loadData(WS.welcome_header_text,"text/html","UTF-8");

Here my WS.welcome_header_text =  <div style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: x-large; background-color: transparent;">Please share your feedback with us</span></div>
```

There is no font-family specified from my backend API but **I want to know what font family is taken by my android web view as default.**

[image]

When It shows Content "Please share your feedback with us" on the above screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebView has provided us with the methods to check the default fonts like -

1. webview.getSettings().getStandardFontFamily()
2. webview.getSettings().getFixedFontFamily()

and As [WebView Safe fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071174/android-webview-safe-font-family) Suggested, My default fonts which are applying, I get it through StandardFontFamily(**sans-serif**)
font-family in my case and Arial/Verdana fonts in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Give your span tag an ID say my-text and run the following code

```
String js = "(function(){var element = document.getElementById( 'my-text' );return window.getComputedStyle( element, null ).getPropertyValue('font-family');})()";

webView.evaluateJavascript(js, new ValueCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
        Log.d("FontFamily", s); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok , let me try it .

Comment: Well I didn't worked for me, as i have already told that "There is no font-family specified from my backend API " , so my <span> tag doesn't have any font-family key