# Android webview custom font using javascript

Tags: javascript, java, android, kotlin, webview

I am trying to show text in webview with custom font which i have selected to show that font style. So following details explain the problem in code

```
public void setFontFamily(String fontFamily) {
        exec("javascript:RE.setFontFamily('" + fontFamily + "');");
    }

So In JS file 

I have following the code

RE.setFontFamily = function(fontFamily) {
    RE.restorerange();
    //document.execCommand("insertHtml", false, "&nbsp")
    console.log("Font Family: "+fontFamily)
    document.execCommand("styleWithCSS", null, true);
    document.execCommand("fontName", false, fontFamily);
    document.execCommand("styleWithCSS", null, false);
};

Above is code snippet i have used

So calling methods are below mentioned

 when (p2) {
            0 -> {
                richEditor.setFontFamily("Times New Roman, Times, serif")
            }
            1 -> {
                richEditor.setFontFamily("Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif")
            }
            2 -> {
                richEditor.setFontFamily("Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif")
            }
            3 -> {
                richEditor.setFontFamily("Comic Sans MS, Cursive, sans-serif")
            }
            else -> {
                richEditor.setFontFamily("Courier New, Courier, monospace")
            }
```

In this above call **Times New Roman and Courier New** is working correctly but other fonts are
not working. Important thing is html is correctly compiled from my input

```
Compiled Html data is below 


<font face="Times New Roman, Times, serif">Times new Roman, </font><div><font face="Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif">trebuchet, </font></div><div><font face="Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif">verdana, </font></div><div><font face="Comic Sans MS, cursive, sans-serif">comic sans</font></div><div><font face="Times New Roman, Times, serif">Times new Roman, </font></div><div><font face="Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif">trebuchet, </font></div><div><font face="Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif">verdana, </font></div><div><font face="Comic Sans MS, cursive, sans-serif">comic sans</font></div>
```