# Implementing @font-face as of late 2012

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I've been spending a few evenings investigating the best way to implement @font-face with todays modern browsers. I am a full time web/system developer with a background as a graphic designer I find the opportunities and possibilites with web design becoming more and more interesting. So, I made some testing and would like to hear if anyone has advices, any better ideas or inputs on this. My testing scenario looks like this.

I tested with ALOT of different online tools and applications but in the end I boiled this down to one online service and one application.

- FontSquirrel, online tool - free. http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator
- FontXChange, application for mac/win - 99$. http://fontgear.net/fontxchange.html

I used a font that was shipped with my Mac, Tamil Sangam MN and Tamil Sangam MN Bold, both came as open type, .otf.

- TamilSangamMN.otf - 290 KB
- TamilSangamMNBold.otf - 271 KB

## Investigating conversion sizes

### FontSquirrel

This is a good online tool, it's very good. There are a few different modes and I've used the Basic and Optimal. The output of my .otf file was svg, ttf, eot and woff.

#### Basic

**Regular**

- TamilSangamMN.svg **233 KB**
- TamilSangamMN.ttf **71 KB**
- TamilSangamMN.eot **25 KB**
- TamilSangamMN.woff **30 KB**
- **Total: 359 KB**

**Bold**

- TamilSangamMNbold.svg **225 KB**
- TamilSangamMNbold.ttf **69 KB**
- TamilSangamMNbold.eot **25 KB**
- TamilSangamMNbold.woff **30 KB**
- **Total: 349 KB**

#### Optimal

First thing I noticed with the optimal fonts are that they are considerably much smaller than the basic variants ~ 260 KB!

**Regular**

- TamilSangamMN.svg **33 KB**
- TamilSangamMN.ttf **25 KB**
- TamilSangamMN.eot **15 KB**
- TamilSangamMN.woff **17 KB**
- **Total: 90 KB**

**Bold**

- TamilSangamMNbold.svg **33 KB**
- TamilSangamMNbold.ttf **25 KB**
- TamilSangamMNbold.eot **15 KB**
- TamilSangamMNbold.woff **17 KB**
- **Total: 90 KB**

### FontXChange

This tool can do so much more than just juggling fonts for the web. It can convert several formats between each other; like opentype, true type, web fonts, post script and so on. The result is overall very high quality the files are so large, almost twice the size of FontSquirrels Basic versions and over 7 times bigger than FontSquirrels Optimal version.

**Regular**

- TamilSangamMN.svg **480 KB**
- TamilSangamMN.ttf **72 KB**
- TamilSangamMN.eot **72 KB**
- TamilSangamMN.woff **80 KB**
- **Total: 704 KB**

**Bold**

- TamilSangamMNbold.svg **463 KB**
- TamilSangamMNbold.ttf **69 KB**
- TamilSangamMNbold.eot **70 KB**
- TamilSangamMNbold.woff **80 KB**
- **Total: 682 KB**

## Setting up the CSS

It puzzled me a bit in the start that the actual order in the font list mattered. Then I discovered that some takes the first format that it finds compatible rather than sticking with the format that is optimal - and it sucks. After some laborations I found that this is the optimal way to format your css (note the order of the file types | ***important!***).

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'TamilSangam';
    src: url('.eot');
    src: url('.svg') format('svg'),          
         url('.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('.woff') format('woff'),
         url('.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

## My test results

### Regular fonts

I did mark the best version with a *

**Firefox MAC (15.0.1)**

- FontSquirrel Optimal: Renders a bit to fat
- FontSquirrel Basic: Renders a bit to fat
- **FontXChange 4.0: Renders a bit to fat, but the kerning is better than the FontSquirrel version ***

**Firefox Windows (15.0.1)**

- FontSquirrel Optimal: Renders very nice
- FontSquirrel Basic: Font gets jagged/choppy
- **FontXChange 4.0: Renders very nice ***

**Safari Mac (6.0)**

- FontSquirrel Optimal: Perfect render
- FontSquirrel Basic: Perfect render
- **FontXChange 4.0: Perfect render ***

**Chrome Mac (21.0)**

- FontSquirrel Optimal: A bit fat
- FontSquirrel Basic: A bit fat
- **FontXChange 4.0: Perfect render ***

**Chrome Windows (21.0)**

- FontSquirrel Optimal: Perfect render
- FontSquirrel Basic: Perfect render
- **FontXChange 4.0: Perfect render ***

**Internet Explorer (9.0)**

- **FontSquirrel Optimal: Perfect render ***
- FontSquirrel Basic: Perfect render
- FontXChange 4.0: Font gets jagged/choppy

### Bold fonts

**Firefox MAC (15.0.1)**

- **FontSquirrel Optimal: Renders very fat ***
- FontSquirrel Basic: Renders very fat
- FontXChange 4.0: Renders very fat, but better kerning *(I would like to select this one for the mac but since the windows version of firefox isn't compatible here it has to go)*

**Firefox Windows (15.0.1)**

- **FontSquirrel Optimal: Renders ok, not very antialiased ***
- FontSquirrel Basic: Font gets jagged/choppy
- FontXChange 4.0: Font gets a bit distorted/jagged

**Safari Mac (6.0)**

- **FontSquirrel Optimal: Perfect render ***
- FontSquirrel Basic: Perfect render
- FontXChange 4.0: Renders fat

**Chrome Mac (21.0)**

- **FontSquirrel Optimal: Perfect render ***
- FontSquirrel Basic: Good render, a few percent to fat
- FontXChange 4.0: Renders fat

**Chrome Windows (21.0)**

- **FontSquirrel Optimal: Perfect render ***
- FontSquirrel Basic: Perfect render
- FontXChange 4.0: Renders very fat

**Internet Explorer (9.0)**

- **FontSquirrel Optimal: Perfect render ***
- FontSquirrel Basic: Perfect render
- FontXChange 4.0: Font gets jagged/choppy

## The final implementation

I usually organize my webfonts in the following pattern, <webfonts> / <conversion source> / <conversion method> / <fonts>

```
/* Regular */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'TamilSangam';
    src: url('webfonts/fontsquirrel/optimal/tamil_sangam_mn.eot');
    src: url('webfonts/fontxchange/TamilSangamMN.svg#TamilSangamMN') format('svg'),
         url('webfonts/fontsquirrel/optimal/tamil_sangam_mn.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('webfonts/fontxchange/TamilSangamMN.woff') format('woff'),
         url('webfonts/fontxchange/TamilSangamMN.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

/* Bold */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'TamilSangam';
    src: url('webfonts/fontsquirrel/optimal/tamil_sangam_mn_bold.eot');
    src: url('webfonts/fontsquirrel/optimal/tamil_sangam_mn_bold.svg#tamil_sangam_mnbold') format('svg'),
         url('webfonts/fontsquirrel/optimal/tamil_sangam_mn_bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('webfonts/fontsquirrel/optimal/tamil_sangam_mn_bold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('webfonts/fontsquirrel/optimal/tamil_sangam_mn_bold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Graphical overview of the result (fullsize at https://i.stack.imgur.com/atb98.png)

[image]

## Conclusions and quests

There isn't one single tool out there that will deliver fonts that render nice on the Mac and Windows in all browsers. You must experiment and test on each font. The methodology posted above is just a simple way and suggestion how to test and experiment with @font-face's.

Is there anything you think I could change in my methods or implementation, is there any application or service that I missed?

All the best / T

Comment: Do you have an actual question to ask or problem to solve? It seems you're merely sharing some research and implementation without asking a concrete question, but just seeking opinions. That seems more apt for a blog than a Q&A site.

Comment: Did update with a more specific question

Comment: I, for one, applaud your thorough post.

Comment: It's a great list. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for IE8. So, I had to move the `.eot?#iefix` lines above the `.svg#TamilSangamMN` lines. I got that from another stackoverflow question about font-face & IE8.

Answer (score 4):

### **@font-face code**

You can add `src: local('ò?'),` which looks for local font with this name, forcing browser to ignore local fonts if they happen to have the same name as your custom font. You can also use this inversely to restrict custom fonts from downloading. *see mobile support*

I generally see the `?#iefix` line second after the standard `.eot` src, though I can't say I have ever needed it, nor know if specific positioning is required (apart from the `.eot` being listed first).

### **Additional control over the fonts**

If you are looking for more control with the fonts in the scenario where fonts fail to load, or dealing with the FOUC in IE, I have a jQuery plugin which will let you hide fonts while they are loading, and allow you to alter the font size on fail so your fallback font doesn't destroy your layout. [How to know if a font (@font-face) has already been loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312323/how-to-know-if-a-font-font-face-has-already-been-loaded/12316349#12316349)

### **IE6-8 bug**

Additionally, IE6-8 can have issues with some font's .eot file. This can be fixed by either ([full guide here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12459447/1455709)):

1. Converting a new .eot file online. If this doesn't work, then the problem is the file properties themselves.
2. Use FontForge to edit the name properties of the font file, then resave and reconvert.

### **CORS**

Seems to only relate to IE and FF. All other browsers (only latest versions tested) don't have problems.

CORS are a common problem with fonts and occur when you are loading fonts from another domain or hostname. This includes specifying your site with a `www` or not. The `@font-face` code needs to be relatively referenced, as does the CSS file. You will also have issues if defining a `<base>` tag in your html. If this isn't possible, or if you don't want to worry about CORS, then you'll need to place the following code in an `.htaccess` file in your font directory:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

### **MIME Types**

404 issues on font serving may be caused by incorrect MIME definitions, see more here: [Mime type for WOFF fonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594823/mime-type-for-woff-fonts)

### **Mobile Support**

Mobile support is pretty bad. Android doesn't properly support it until 4.0, and Windows Mobile, as far as I am aware doesn't support it at all. I am investigating any work around or solutions for this. Best I have so far is to use [How to know if a font (@font-face) has already been loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312323/how-to-know-if-a-font-font-face-has-already-been-loaded/12316349#12316349) to display a picture of the text on font load failure. This really only works for site titles and icons, otherwise it's a horribly poor work around, bad for SEO and bad UX.

[See `@font-face` support.](http://caniuse.com/fontface)

Additionally, Android 2.2 - x.x.x versions will fail if your `@font-face` uses `local()`, which is also used as a fix for IE. Multiple stylesheets may be needed if you want to cover all your bases. See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4520467/1455709

### **SVG and Chrome**

Chrome won't use the SVG font if you're including the `#fontName` in the url. It'll also use WOFF before SVG - and doesn't do a good job rendering it. This is probably the reason why everyone sooks about crappy font rendering in Chrome... To overcome this is an additional @font-face declaration is required:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'myFont';
        src: url('fonts/myFont.svg') format('svg');
    }
}
```