# Difference between format('embedded-opentype') and format('eot')

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I am using compass module to generate my css files from sccs files.

Earlier i was working only on Linux and the when the css file was created, the fon-face attribute looked like below :

```
@font-face {
    font-family:"NationalReg";
    src: url('../fonts/national-regular.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/national-regular.eot?#iefix') format('eot'), url('../fonts/telecomnational-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/national-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/national-regular.svg') format('svg');
}
```

Now i am working on Windows, and the css file generated has below structure :

```
@font-face {
    font-family:"NationalReg";
    src: url('../fonts/national-regular.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/national-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/telecomnational-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/national-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/national-regular.svg') format('svg');
}
```

Notice the difference in the format("eot") and format("embedded-opentype").

I understand that this is added for IE8 and below browsers. But will it create any problems if two different format tags are used (in windows/linux).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing @font-face as of late 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537892/implementing-font-face-as-of-late-2012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen both values being used, but I was not able to find any documented difference.

The [Microsoft @font-face documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530757%28VS.85%29.aspx) says (emphasis mine):

> To specify specific font formats (only for externally referenced font files), use a format hint (format(fontFormat)) where fontFormat is a comma-separated list of format strings that denote supported font formats. **Possible fontFormat values are "woff", "truetype", "opentype", and "embedded-opentype".** The format hint is optional starting in Internet Explorer 9. (format hints are not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions and are ignored.)

Since the .eot file format is only for Microsoft browsers anyway, I would in this case just take their word for it and use `format('embedded-opentype')`.